How to correctly get source location of static function callExpr using Clang AST Matcher?
I am trying to build a custom clang-tidy for refactoring purposes and I am having trouble getting the correct source location for static member function callExpr. For example:
    class Test
    {
        public:
        static void foo(){}
    };

and here is clang-tidy side of code:

    Finder->addMatcher(
    traverse(TraversalKind::TK_IgnoreUnlessSpelledInSource,
             callExpr(callee(functionDecl(hasAncestor(
                          namespaceDecl(hasName("my_namespace"))))))
                 .bind("call_expr")),
    this);

I am using MatchedCallExpr->getExprLoc() and it output
Test::foo()
~~~~
^
This function name should blahblahblah

But my expected output should look like
Test::foo()
      ~~~
      ^
This function name should blahblahblah


To get the location of the member name foo in the call expression
Test::foo(), you need to navigate down to the
DeclRefExpr
node, then call its getLocation() method.
To see that the AST has DeclRefExpr, dump it like this:
$ cat test.cc
// test.cc

namespace my_namespace {
  struct A {
    static void foo();
  };

  void caller()
  {
    A::foo();
  }
}

// EOF

$ clang -fsyntax-only -Xclang -ast-dump test.cc | tail
  | | |-CopyAssignment simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
  | | |-MoveAssignment exists simple trivial needs_implicit
  | | `-Destructor simple irrelevant trivial needs_implicit
  | |-CXXRecordDecl 0x5569ec185cb8 <col:3, col:10> col:10 implicit struct A
  | `-CXXMethodDecl 0x5569ec185dc8 <line:5:5, col:21> col:17 used foo 'void ()' static
  `-FunctionDecl 0x5569ec185ea8 <line:8:3, line:11:3> line:8:8 caller 'void ()'
    `-CompoundStmt 0x5569ec186080 <line:9:3, line:11:3>
      `-CallExpr 0x5569ec186060 <line:10:5, col:12> 'void'
        `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x5569ec186048 <col:5, col:8> 'void (*)()' <FunctionToPointerDecay>
          `-DeclRefExpr 0x5569ec185fe8 <col:5, col:8> 'void ()' lvalue CXXMethod 0x5569ec185dc8 'foo' 'void ()'

Notice the last line.
Your current matcher matches the CallExpr node, and then uses the
callee matcher to filter based on the declaration of the callee.
But callee is overloaded, and can also be used to filter based on the
expression aspect, which is what we need here.  (See the
AST Matchers Reference
for more information, albeit very terse.)
This matcher will do the same thing but bind the DeclRefExpr:
  callExpr(
    callee(
      // The `callee` matcher is overloaded.  Select the one that
      // zooms in on the callee *expression* rather than declaration.
      expr(
        // Skip the function-to-pointer decay node.
        ignoringImplicit(
          // This is the DeclRefExpr we want.
          declRefExpr(
            // We can refine based on *its* declaration if needed
            // (rather than directly from `callee`).
            hasDeclaration(
              functionDecl(
                hasAncestor(
                  namespaceDecl(
                    hasName(
                      "my_namespace"
                    )
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          ).bind("e")   // Bind the DeclRefExpr.
        )
      )
    )
  )

Then once you've pulled the bound node out as a DeclRefExpr, its
getLocation says where the member name foo is.  Note that there is
also a getBeginLoc method that returns the location of Test.
(Beware: I only tested the above matcher with
clang-query,
not by putting into a C++ checker.  It probably works as-is, but might
need minor adjustment.)
